# When using data.table in a package, R CMD check NOTEs: no visible global function definition for '.'

Tags: r, data.table

I have tried (via roxygen2) `@import data.table` and importing just the functions I use (`@importFrom data.table data.table rbindlist setkey setDT := .SD`. Either way I get this warning about the `.` "function", which I assume is from this kind of usage:
`dt[x, .(a, b, c)]`. I can't find any way to import `.` without causing an error.

And as a followup question, is there a recommended way to hide the `no visible binding for global variable` for `a`, `b`, and `c`? There are quite a few other questions about this latter NOTE but I haven't seen a satisfying answer. `globalVariable` and setting the column names to placeholder values elsewhere in the function are ugly hacks. Should I switch to some other method of specifying the columns which would solve both issues?

Comment: One alternative is to substitute `.()` with `list()` in your code.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/850

Comment: @Matt Could you find the solution ? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I haven't seen a non-hacky solution yet. Assigning NULL in a local variable almost defeats the point of using the NSE version in the first place. Whereas `globalVariables` pollutes the global environment as mentioned below. A good solution would allow data.table to disable checking for its NSE syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `globalVariables` you can also define those variables locally, not polluting global environment.
I will copy my comment from [github issue Rdatatable/data.table#850](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/850#issuecomment-259466153)

> you can just assign NULL to the variable before using it (not confuse with override it). So you are not defining global variables, but just defining them locally in a function where you are using them.

Worth to note that issue is relevant to any NSE interface, not just data.table. NSE basically makes CRAN check unable to investigate if variables used has been defined in some NSE interface, thus raising a note.

Answer (score 1):

I think `globalVariables()` is the best way to go... If you choose to use the `globalVariables()` method, this function will automate the process for you. It requires the packages **pkgload** and **codetools**:

```
globs <- function(    
  fun,    
  pkg = rprojroot::find_package_root_file(),    
  ignore = c(":=", ".SD", ".BY", ".N", ".I", ".GRP")    
){    
  pkg <- basename(pkg)    
  ns  <- c(   
    ls(pkgload::pkg_env("base")),    
    ls(pkgload::ns_env(pkg)),    
    ls(pkgload::imports_env(pkg)),    
    ignore    
  )     

  res <- sort(setdiff(   
    codetools::findGlobals(fun),    
    ns   
  ))

  cat(strwrap(paste0("utils::globalVariables(c(", paste('"', res, '"', collapse = ", ", sep = ""), "))"), width = 80), sep = "\n")

  res    
}


#example
globs(data.table::between)
```

You obviously still have to define the functions in `ignore` as globalVariables somewhere in your package once.

I'll put it in a Package/RStudio addin when I get around to it and revisit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Defining `.` as an alias for `list` seems to be sufficient. I got rid of the NOTE by adding the following line to the first (alphabetically ordered) .R file in my package:

```
`.` <- list
```